# Use of $ operator

Tags: r, operators

my question is regarding the $ operator for accessing a particular part of my dataframe.

Here below is my data frame

```
structure(list(Treatment = structure(c(11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L), .Label = c("Chlora", "Gen", "Lin", "Metro", "Metro+Pen", 
"Metro+Rif", "Metro+Rif+Pen", "Pen", "Pen+Rif", "Rif", "Untreated"
), class = "factor"), CDW = c(0.833, 0.867, 0.833, 2.7, 3.3, 
3.133), Chlorophyll = c(1.098, 1.376, 1.64, 34.714, 37.773, 40.54
), EPS = c(0.092, 0.067, 0.092, 0.571, 0.591, 0.597), Day = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 10L, 10L, 10L), TreatmentDay = structure(c(21L, 21L, 
21L, 22L, 22L, 22L), .Label = c("Chlora0", "Chlora10", "Gen0", 
"Gen10", "Lin0", "Lin10", "Metro+Pen0", "Metro+Pen10", "Metro+Rif+Pen0", 
"Metro+Rif+Pen10", "Metro+Rif0", "Metro+Rif10", "Metro0", "Metro10", 
"Pen+Rif0", "Pen+Rif10", "Pen0", "Pen10", "Rif0", "Rif10", "Untreated0", 
"Untreated10"), class = "factor"), richness = c(36L, 37L, 39L, 
31L, 31L, 24L), shannon = c(3.35867443756547, 3.37354007038303, 
3.43640985397324, 3.16018680691703, 3.15718684762791, 2.85288614815093
)), .Names = c("Treatment", "CDW", "Chlorophyll", "EPS", "Day", 
"TreatmentDay", "richness", "shannon"), row.names = c("Day0F1", 
"Day0F2", "Day0F3", "Day10F1", "Day10F2", "Day10F3"), class = "data.frame")
```

I can use

```
Unt$richness
[1] 36 37 39 31 31 24
```

But if I want to do an anova test, I get an error message saying I cannot use $ with atomic vectors

```
Unt_Richness_anova <- aov(Unt$richness, TreatmentDay)
```

So, I find it confusing I can use $ operator in atomic vector in one instance but not for the other.
Can someone help out?

Comment: What language is this? Your question needs more **tags**. `operators` alone is too generic.

Comment: A data.frame is a special type of list. You can see this with `is.list(Unt)`. A list is specifically NOT an atomic vector. You can see this with `is.atomic(Unt)`. `Unt$richness`, the vector stored in the data.frame, is atomic, `is.atomic(Unt$richness)`.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the source code of the `aov()` function, it is actually a call to another function called `terms()` that is causing this error.

Now if the `terms()` function is called when the data frame is not specified within the `aov()` function, it seems that the `terms()` function will only take a *formulae* styled argument which is passed from the `aov()` function.

Notice that the following code does not work (as you specified):

```
Unt_Richness_anova <- aov(Unt$richness, Unt$TreatmentDay)
```

If you express the two variables as a formula then everything works as it should:

```
Unt_Richness_anova <- aov(Unt$richness ~ Unt$TreatmentDay)
```

So the problem is not with the `$` operator but in fact with the `terms()` function. It seems the `terms()` function can only deal with separate variables if they belong to the same dataframe **AND** the dataframe is specified within the `aov()` function.

Why this is the case I cannot answer but hopefully someone else can shed some light?